# Exact string matching in python - Comparison of two list elements

Tags: python, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare two list-elements in python. If the two elements match exactly, true should be returned, otherwise false.

The elements look like this:

```
list1_element_1: ['GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1']

list2_element_1: ['GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1.100']
```

I tried multiple ways of comparing these two elements, including regex.
The following is the function I use to compare the elements:

```
def find_word(text,search):
    result = re.findall('\\b'+search+'\\b', text)
    if len(result)>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Expected results:

```
find_word('GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1.100','GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1') FALSE
```

Actual results:

```
find_word('GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1.100','GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1') TRUE, because 'GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1' is existing in element 'GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1.100', I guess?
```

True should only be returned if both list elements are exactly the same!

Thanks!

Comment: why not simply `return text == search` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to tell you this, but you're overthinking it - you can just use the regular `==` operator for this:

```
list1_element_1: ['GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1']
list2_element_1: ['GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1.100']
list3_element_1: ['GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1']

print(list1_element_1 == list2_element_1)  # False
print(list1_element_1 == list3_element_1)  # True
```

For strings, the `==` operator returns `True` if they match exactly. For lists, it returns `True` if the lengths are the same and corresponding elements match exactly (the `.__eq__()` method is used for this comparison, if you're trying to compare custom classes - all built-in classes have their notions of equality implemented). So if you have a list of strings, you can test whether or not it's equal to another list of strings:

```
print(['str1', 'str2', 'str3'] == ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'])  # True
print(['str1', 'str2', 'str3'] == ['str1', 'str3', 'str2'])  # False
```

Comment: Thank you! Another quick question: what do i do if there is more than 'GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1.100' in list2? For example comparing 'GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1' against  'GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1.3108            1.1.1.1   Up              Up       default'? This should return false, whereas 'GigabitEthernet0/6/4/1            1.1.1.1   Up              Up       default' should return true...

Comment: You might want to split the string into smaller strings, separated by spaces (e.g. `list1[0] == list2[0].split(' ')[0]`). I'd advise getting as specific as possible with your comparisons - if you can compare individual strings instead of the lists containing them, and that's all your program needs, then do that

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
def find_word(text, search):
    return text == search
```